# Convert 32 bit float audio to 16 bit byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I am getting audio using the NAudio library which returns a 32 bit `float[]` of audio data.  I'm trying to find a way to convert this to a 16 bit `byte[]` for playback.

```
private void sendData(float[] samples)
{
    Buffer.BlockCopy(samples, 0, byteArray, 0, samples.Length);
    byte[] encoded = codec.Encode(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    waveProvider.AddSamples(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    s.Send(encoded, SocketFlags.None);
}
```

The audio being sent to `waveProvider` is coming out static-y — I don't think I'm converting correctly.  How can I convert to a byte array of 16 bit samples?

Answer (score 5):

[`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) copies a number of bytes, but you're passing it a number of elements. Since a `float` is 4 bytes and a `byte` is obviously 1, you're using a fourth of `samples` to fill up half of `byteArray`, leaving the rest untouched. That probably won't give you very good audio, to say the least.

What you'll need to do is convert from a floating-point value between −1 and 1 to a 16-bit integer value between −2<sup>15</sup> and 2<sup>15</sup>−1. If we convert to `short`s rather than `byte`s, it's rather simple:

```
shortSample = (short)Math.Floor(floatSample * 32767);
```

<sup>(If you know that `floatSample` will always be less than 1, you should multiply by 32,768 rather than 32,767.)</sup>
Of course, you want a byte array rather than a `short` array. Unfortunately, you've not given enough information for that last step. There's two things that you'll need to know: endianness and signedness. If it's unsigned, you'll need to convert that `short` to a `ushort` by adding 32,768. Then you need to split each `short` or `ushort` up into two bytes. Endianness determines the order, but you'll probably need to do some bit-shifting.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's starting to make some more sense.  I'm not really familiar with Endianness but I will look through the library to see if I can figure that out.  Just for my own learning - why do they need to be slit into 2 bytes?  It looks like this is happening when I use the GetBytes method (byte[] samplesByteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(shortSample);)

Comment: @user547794: If it takes a 16-bit byte array and each byte is 8 bits, you need two bytes per 16-bit short.

Comment: Isn't the `Math.Floor` call redundant?