# How to play audio samples without writing it into to a file?

Tags: c#, naudio

I get audio samples (as float array) from another method
and I want to play this float array without writing any files to disk.

For this example I get samples from audio file:

```
var file = new AudioFileReader(stereoFile);

int startPos = 0;
int endPos = 138890;

var sampleArray = new float[endPos - startPos];

file.Read(sampleArray, startPos, sampleArray.Length);
```

How can I play `sampleArray`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I play byte array of audio raw data using NAudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792548/how-can-i-play-byte-array-of-audio-raw-data-using-naudio)

Comment: @00110001 this is byte array, not float sample array. this answer not work with samples

Comment: @Sinatr unfortunately not.

Comment: Sinatr's answer should work once you have converted those floating-point samples to e.g. 16-bit signed samples.

Comment: @AKX This is possible way, but if I correctly understand this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689410/convert-32-bit-float-audio-to-16-bit-byte-array this way not easyest. Maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: It's not really particularly _hard_ ... but you could also try if using a [float data format](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/889ec87e1e8153504de330cacb2e7ca3e6437c5a/NAudio/Wave/WaveFormats/WaveFormat.cs#L135) would work directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find next solution and it work for me:

```
        var file = new AudioFileReader(stereoFile);

        WaveFormat waveFormat = file.WaveFormat;

        int startPos = 2403;
        int endPos = 41265;

        if (startPos % 2 != 0)
        {
            startPos += 1;
        }

        if (endPos % 2 != 0)
        {
            endPos += 1;
        }

        if (waveFormat.Channels == 2)
        {
            startPos *= 2;
            endPos *= 2;
        }

        var allSamples = new float[file.Length / (file.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8)];

        file.Read(allSamples, 0, allSamples.Length);

        Span<float> samplesSpan = allSamples;
        Span<float> trackSpan = samplesSpan.Slice(startPos, endPos - startPos);
```

^
upper code  to take correct samples for tests.
code below - my solution

```
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        IgnoreDisposeStream ids = new IgnoreDisposeStream(ms);

        using (WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(ids, waveFormat))
        {
            waveFileWriter.WriteSamples(trackSpan.ToArray(), 0, endPos-startPos);
        }


        ms.Position = 0;
        WaveStream waveStream = new WaveFileReader(ms);
        WaveOutEvent waveOutEvent = new WaveOutEvent();
        waveOutEvent.Init(waveStream);
        waveOutEvent.Play();
```

Answer (score 2):

`RawSourceWaveStream` is designed for the situation where you have audio in a byte array or `MemoryStream` and want to play it directly. You can learn more about it and see an example of how to use it [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RawSourceWaveStream.md)

Comment: How can i play sample array with RawSourceWaveStream? RawSourceWaveStream can work with byte[] or Stream but not with float[]

Comment: You can use the WaveBuffer class as a way to cast between the two, or use something like Buffer.BlockCopy to copy float samples into a byte[]